# why is this loop working infinitely?

Tags: java

```
class kk{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n=0;
        for (byte i = 0; i<=255; i++) 
        { 
             n++;
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

The above for loop goes on infinitely  . I would appreciate it if somebody could answer why ?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it's worth noting that your `byte` variable will actually largely be treated as an `int` in the generated bytecode, so using a `byte` here would improve neither speed nor memory consumption.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: indeed it is slower by using a byte, the operation is done through `ILOAD 1`, `ICONST_1`, `IADD` and then result is converted back to a byte to be stored thrugh `I2B`. So there is even an unnecessary opcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Because byte values are in the range of `[-128, 127]`.

Hence, when the byte 127 is incremented it overflows to -128 and your loop continues indefinitely.

Answer (score 9):

Because any numerical value in Java is by default **signed**.

So a `byte` holds values in range `[-128, 127]`, a range that always satisfies the condition of your `for` loop. Whenever `i == 127`, adding `1` to `i` turn it into `-128`.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
for (byte i = 0; i<=255; i++)
```

is an infinite loop, because `i` will always be `<= 255`.

As Java `byte`s are signed, their value can range from `-2^8`(is -128) to `(2^8)-1` (is 127).

Once `i` is 127, adding one will turn it to -128 which is obviously smaller than `255`. So this loop will run forever.